# Docker login via ssh always asks for password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

I a trying to create an Ubuntu image with an "ubuntu" user who can log into the container via ssh without using a password.  It asks for a password when I try to log in.

Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM     ubuntu:latest
ENV USER ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $USER
RUN adduser $USER sudo
ADD authorized_keys /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown $USER /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
EXPOSE 22
CMD    ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Step 1: check logs, maybe something is wrong with authorized key?

Answer (score 2):

The permissions were not set properly on authorized_keys.  This Dockerfile worked:

```
FROM     ubuntu:latest
ENV USER ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $USER
RUN adduser $USER sudo
ADD authorized_keys /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown $USER /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod 700 /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
EXPOSE 22
CMD    ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```